# AJAX received datas size (responseText.length) is smaller than the original file size?

Tags: javascript, ajax, utf-8

I would like to check received datas via an AJAX request in javascript.
To do that I need to check the size of the received datas and compare it with the original file size on the server.

```
var xhr_object = new XMLHttpRequest();
... // Send AJAX request
var RetAjax = xhr_object.responseText;
console.log(RetAjax.length);
```

I have tested with different type of files.

- With images files as jpeg, the AJAX received datas size is about 70% of the original size.
- With a Text file, this is about 96%.
  But there is an interesting thing I can see with the following test :

I have tried to encode first the Text file in ANSI format and then in UTF-8 without BOM. Please see results on the table below.

Encodage --- ORG File Size --- AJAX Datas Size

ANSI ---------- **4,792 Bytes** ------ 4,506 Bytes

UTF-8 --------- 4,986 Bytes ------ **4,792 Bytes**

As we can see, the file size is the same between the ANSI ORG file and the UTF-8 AJAX received datas.

So my questions are :

- What is the relationship between the original file size and the AJAX received datas ?
- Is there an encoding problem with TEXT files between client and server ?
- What about with other types of files as image files ? Is there a way to check the right file size ?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Regards

Comment: Have you checked if/how the server is compressing the Ajax response? This info should be in the response header, something like `Content-Encoding:gzip`

Comment: I didn't see the "Content-Encoding" param in the Ajax response header. Only the "Content-type: text/plain" appears. I have used the getAllResponseHeaders() javascript function to get it. I can see by using phpinfo() on the PHP server that there is a line "Content-Encoding  gzip" in the "HTTP Headers Information" section.

Comment: I have also tried to compress into a ZIP file my differents files and the results don't match with this possibility : My TEXT file size is smaller than the AJAX received datas size and My JPEG files size are greater than the AJAX received datas size (JPEG can't be compress too much, this is always a compressed file !)